# Errors installing pygraphviz on mac os 11.6

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pygraphviz in order to get layouts for my network. However, I have trouble installing pygraphviz using `pip install pygraphviz`. I get the following lengthy error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/w0/pv1mwphj1t552sml25d44bq40000gn/T/pip-install-dabvxss7/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/w0/pv1mwphj1t552sml25d44bq40000gn/T/pip-install-dabvxss7/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/w0/pv1mwphj1t552sml25d44bq40000gn/T/pip-wheel-ktbtqll_
       cwd: /private/var/folders/w0/pv1mwphj1t552sml25d44bq40000gn/T/pip-install-dabvxss7/pygraphviz/
  Complete output (71 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/scraper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/agraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/testing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_scraper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_readwrite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_string.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_html.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_node_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_drawing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_subgraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_close.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_edge_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_clear.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_layout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attribute_defaults.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  running egg_info
  writing pygraphviz.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
  warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
  warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
  writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz.i -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  running build_ext
  building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:1756:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        0,                                    /* tp_print */
        ^
  /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
      ^
  /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:1923:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        0,                                    /* tp_print */
        ^
  /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
      ^
  /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2711:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found
  #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  2 warnings and 1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py clean for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
    Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/w0/pv1mwphj1t552sml25d44bq40000gn/T/pip-install-dabvxss7/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/w0/pv1mwphj1t552sml25d44bq40000gn/T/pip-install-dabvxss7/pygraphviz/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/w0/pv1mwphj1t552sml25d44bq40000gn/T/pip-record-p4ku8efv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pygraphviz
         cwd: /private/var/folders/w0/pv1mwphj1t552sml25d44bq40000gn/T/pip-install-dabvxss7/pygraphviz/
    Complete output (71 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/scraper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/agraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/testing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_scraper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_readwrite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_string.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_html.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_node_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_drawing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_subgraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_close.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_edge_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_clear.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_layout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attribute_defaults.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    running egg_info
    writing pygraphviz.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
    writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz.i -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    running build_ext
    building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o
    pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:1756:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          0,                                    /* tp_print */
          ^
    /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:1923:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          0,                                    /* tp_print */
          ^
    /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2711:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found
    #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2 warnings and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue. I've been going through a lot of stack overlfow threads, but nothing worked. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

PyGraphviz requires the graphviz library to be installed. The easiest way to do this is probably to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_sv), as described in the macOS section of the [PyGraphviz installation docs](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however direct recommendations are not working properly.
So, the sequence is the following:

1. `brew install graphviz`
2. `pip install --install-option="--include-path=/opt/local/include" --install-option="--library-path=/opt/local/lib" pygraphviz`

The second — is how to force `pip` to find a correct path to header files after brew install.